# Cassandra: dropping keyspace with tables containing numerous user defined types

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am in a situation where I would like to drop a keyspace which can also *safely* delete all the contained tables' various user defined types.

The official document of CQL Cassandra states:

> "Immediate, irreversible removal of the keyspace, including objects
>   such as tables, functions, and data it contains. "

However, from the document I cannot make out if it also highlights removal of user defined types. Could someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DROP KEYSPACE command drops the keyspace and all objects that are part of that keyspace: data, tables/colum families, user defined types, indexes.

Before the actual drop,  snapshot of the keyspace is taken. This can be enabled/disabled using auto_snapshot parameter in cassandra.yaml. Default value for this parameter is true.